# PHP header redirect not working on production, blank page

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, fastcgi

I am about to throw the towel in. Can somebody help me figure this out.
On my local dev server this bit of PHP works fine, its just doing a redirect by constructing a url out of some variables. So I get redirected to this page as expected.

```
$status = "0"; //unsubscribed
header('Location:http://www.skandium.com/manage-your-mailing-list.asp?status='.$status);
die();
```

On the production server I just get a blank page. I know the PHP page itself is working because all other things that happen upto and before this line work fine. I can replace this line with a simple `echo` and can see the URL is correct also.

**Other details:**

- Hosted on a windows box (dev is also windows)
- same PHP version running via FASTCGI

**EDIT: the plot thickens**

The following code on its own in a new page works fine on production. Still doesn't explain why the above code works locally and not on production. All I seemed to have ruled out is that the header redirect statement by itself is not the culprit.

```
<?php 

//test.php

//prevent page caching
header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: -1");

$status = "0"; //unsubscribed

header('Location:http://www.abc.com/manage-your-mailing-list.php?status='.$status);
die();

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your redirect to be a full http path instead of a relative path page name?

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? What do they mention?

Comment: At the beginning of the page try adding "ob_start();" in php tag. hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: @Arjan what log files should I be looking at?

Comment: @balanv 'ob_start();' causes the page to not load at all, the browser loading indicator just keeps going and going...

Comment: @Ben I just tried it and it still behaves the same

Comment: @Moin I'm not too familiar with IIS, but I'm sure it has something like IIS logs or HTTP logs.

Comment: try enabling error reporting.. sometimes when the error reporting is off you will only see a blank page... ob_start helped me most times when i stuck with while using header().. thats why suggested it..

Comment: Check if `headers_sent()`  is true before that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these worked.

I ended up echoing a `meta` redirect.

I could also have echoed a javascript `location.replace`

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is no whitespace before php tag

Answer (score 2):

A few thing you can try is:

- Check if `headers_sent()` is `true` before sending the redirect header
- Set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`
- Use firebug to check what (if any) headers are being sent to the browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
header('Location: http://www.abc.com/manage-your-mailing-list.php?status='.$status)
```

I just add a space between colon(:) and the url..
I don't know this happened to others, but sometimes this kind of things happened to me and sometime this works for whatever reasons..

Also, have you tried relative path?
or at other pages, i mean does "header location" works on other places?
or it happens on this script only?

Answer (score 0):

Is the file UTF-8 encoded? *Any output* can prevent the code to be executed, including a BOM. Maybe the encoding was not explicitly set, but your dev machine assumed UTF-8 (and ignored the mark) while your production server didn't.

Comment: How do I verify this? I am using Notepad++ and Under the Encoding menu option I see 'Encoding in ANSI' checked. There are other options like 'UTF-8 without BOM' etc.

Comment: UTF-8 is without BOM per se. I don't know how you can change the encoding to UTF-8 in notepad++; you should refer to the application's doc. (Also, the encoding should be changed for the includes as well).

Comment: Ok I saved the page and any includes as UTF-8 and it still behaves the same.